# Why are my particles behaving weirdly? Resting in odd shape, ignoring passive rigidbody mesh

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation, fluid-simulation

I try do do an animation where a rock gets grinded into powder. for that purpose i created a particle system that spawns the powder over time. Because i want to rotate the bow later and pour the powder out of it, i made the bowl rigidbody passive and the particles rigidbody active. Besides the particles completly ignoring the mesh shape of the bowl (but not passing through??), they also seem to rest in a cylindric shape. did i miss something? Is there a better way to do this? Thank you so much in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]